# Rails - ActiveRecord: select Items by array of conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given an array of hashes:

```
conditions = [ 
  {:name => "Jim",  :title => "PM" },
  {:name => "Tony", :title => "PM" },
  {:name => "Jim",  :title => "CEO" } 
]
```

is there a nice way to get back models that match those conditions?

Something like:

```
User.where(conditions)
```

It seems I can pass a hash of conditions for a single hash - I'm after support for an array of hashes

Thanks

Comment: so you want users where name is jim and title is pm OR where name is tony and title is pm OR name is jim and title is CEO.  is that right?

Comment: yeah - that's correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [any_of](https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of) gem then

```
User.where.any_of(*conditions)
```